# PhpStorm: tslint for automatically fix

Tags: phpstorm, tslint

Can tslint in Phpstorm automatically fix code for me?

Comment: No, it just shows you where errors are and you'll have to fix them yourself

Comment: Thanks. That's inconvenient.

Answer (score 3):

Yes **tslint can now autofix** some errors. Run this at the root of your code:

```
tslint src/**/*.ts --fix
```